# Proving if and only if statements regarding sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Still sort of new to proofs and I'm not sure how to approach some of the questions. Both of these come from Tao's Analysis I and I have done all the exercises that don't involve iff statements and are just direct proofs about set equality so I think my problem stems from the fact I'm not sure how to deal with if then statements in the context of sets. I have read posts on MathSE about proving if then statements regarding sets but they didn't help me much because they didn't really explain why we do what we do.

Let $A$,$B$,$C$ be sets. Show that $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$. Furthermore, show that $C\subseteq A$ and $C\subseteq B$ if and only if $C \subseteq A\cap B$.

For this first one I kind of came up with a proof. The first two statements are trivial since $A\cap B \implies A\land B$. Assume $C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$. Suppose $x\in C$ then by the assumption $x\in A$ and $x\in B \iff x\in A\cap B$ thus $C\subseteq A\cap B$. Now assume $C\subseteq A\cap B$ and suppose $x\in C$. Then $x\in A\cap B$ so $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ so $C\subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$.

If that above proof is right then it still feels weird because I didn't use the two statements I was asked to prove. I can see maybe a way to prove $C\subseteq A\cap B$ implies $C\subseteq A$ and $C\subseteq B$ but not the other way round. Let $x\in C$ and assume $C\subseteq A\cap B$. Then $x\in A\cap B$. So $x \in A\cap B \subseteq A$ and $x \in A\cap B \subseteq B$ thus $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ so $C\subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$.

---

For the second proof you have to show that $A\subseteq B$, $A\cup B=B$ and $A\cap B=A$ are all logically equivalent.

Let's say that I proved $A\subseteq B\iff A\cup B=B$ although it might be wrong. Now proving something like $A\cup B=B \iff A\cap B=A$ is where I struggle to formulate a proof.

Let's do $A\cup B=B \implies A\cap B=A$. Assume $A\cup B=B$. We want to show $A\cap B=A$. Now I should pick an arbitrary element $x$ right? But from which set? Or should I do it for both cases $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\in A$?

Maybe everything I've written here is wrong. That could very much happen because these proofs all just came from my inexperienced intuition of what a proof of this type should probably look like while I probably couldn't justify every step.

Comment: To prove an equivalence like $P\iff Q$ we prove $P\implies Q$ and $Q\implies P$ separately.

Comment: Obviously, I did that on the post as well. I didn’t do it for the second one because I wasn’t sure if the start was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logical equivalence of the statements $P_1,P_2,\dots,P_n$ it is often shown

$$ P_1 \Rightarrow P_2 \Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow P_n \Rightarrow P_1 $$

where you create some kind of a logic loop. Equivalently, you can create an iff chain such as

$$ P_1 \iff P_2 \iff \dots \iff P_n $$

In your case this could be

$$A\cup B=B \iff A\subseteq B\iff A\cap B = A$$

So, if you have already proven $A\cup B=B \iff A\subseteq B$, then it is enough to prove $A\subseteq B\iff A\cap B = A$, which could be much easier.

**Edit.** I understand your question clearly now. So if you want to show $A\cup B = B \implies A\cap B = A$ your assumption would be "for all $x \in A \cup B$ we have $x \in B$ and vice versa". Not picking an arbitrary element from a set.

The sketch of the proof can go like this: Suppose $x \in A$. Then by the assumption $x \in B$. Therefore, $x \in A\cap B$, which implies $A \subseteq A \cap B$. Since $A \cap B \subseteq A$ is true for all sets you get the equality.

Comment: This was helpful and now the assumption is clear to me. Now about starting the proof. You said "Suppose $x\in A$". But why did you make that choice? Could you have done the same by picking $B$? For example another exercise similar to the first asks to prove $(A\subseteq C)\land (B\subseteq C)\iff A\cup B\subseteq C$. Now to prove the direction $(\implies )$. I will assume that $\forall x \in A$ we have $x\in C$, similarly $\forall x \in B$ we have $x\in C$. But now what do I choose here? The set $C$ appears in both assumptions but if I were to assume $x\in C$ then I couldn't continue since ...

Comment: ... I couldn't get any use out of my assumptions since both of them conclude something about $C$. So I probably should pick $x\in A$ or $x \in B$ here. I should probably do both though right? I'm not sure how the logistics of that works. I'm basically afraid that I could suppose $x\in X$ in some exercise and even if I get a correct result then the proof would still be wrong because I should've supposed $x\in Y$ instead.

Comment: Or do I suppose $x\in A\cup B$ for the exercise I mentioned? Upon further thought I think this should be the way. Also the proof follows immediately.

Comment: I could have chosen $x\in B$, but this wouldn't make any progress. As you discovered yourself, the choices should be useful for what you wanted to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Your first proofs are correct. If I correctly understand the question, it is whether the word "Furthermore" means that the previous statements need to be used in proving the following one. I didn't read it that way, I think "furthermore" means the same thing as "also".

And yes, often proving an if and only if statement will be done by proving the if direction and the only if direction separately and combining them, as you have done.

Comment: I wasn’t actually unsure of whether iff statements can be proven by proving each direction separately but seeing as this is what people perceived from the post, then it’s probably my fault. The trouble lied in whether each if then proof was done correctly.